# Safely replace table data with new one

Tags: php, mysql, web-services

I use an atom feed to get information about the diseases,countries and vaccines from a [webservice](http://www.1177.se/api/) to 
regularly update my database tables.
Everytime I call the webservice, I compare the last updated date, if new information is available, I empty my table and insert all the data again.

But the data is very big and  if somehow any error occur during the process, the entire table is left empty(because I truncate the table in the beginning of the update).

I am thinking of inserting the data first into a temporary table and when done sucessfully then only empty and copy  to the real table.
But I would like to hear from the experts if this is the right solution and whether some other better solutions exist. (I'm using PHP and mysql)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i'm in your case, I will use 3 tables on my database. First table is to hold your current data, second table will be used to hold new data and the last one is used for old data.

And here's how to play with them :

1. When your script receive data from web service, put it on second table (new data) and at the same time, move your first table (current data) into third table (old data)
2. Do some comparison, and if you find something new between them, put it into current data.
3. If something is not right, you still can safely replace with with previous data stored on 'old data'.

So, you won't lose any data anymore in the future... Hope it helps...

Comment: Thank you very much for your idea.
I already have 6 tables to fill from the web-service and managing 6x3=18 tables sounded like doing too much.
But instead I think the better idea would be creating two temporary tables instead of the permanent table for each table like you mentioned for old and new and in this manner I like your idea.

I am accepting the answer but I am  waiting for more ideas from others.